# How to use Action.Submit in adaptive card to mimic user input

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, botframework, adaptive-cards

My goal is to achieve [MessageFactory.SuggestedActions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/messagefactory?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#botbuilder-core-messagefactory-suggestedactions) with my "welcomeCard" adaptive card.

I.e., In my adaptive card (welcome card), I have a few buttons for user to press, each with an `Action.Submit` type

```
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Get fundamental",
      "data": {
        "inputValue": "Get fundamental"
      }
    },
```

When clicked, it should be **treated as the user's initial input** and passed to CLU to parse intent/entities.

My bot is structured with [core-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/typescript_nodejs/13.core-bot) as template. I am able to parse the `inputValue` in my context, captured in [`onMessage()` handler](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/typescript_nodejs/13.core-bot/src/bots/dialogBot.ts#L37).

My question is, how do I use `inputValue` as the initial user input? In bot code, I'm guessing I need to bypass the [`introStep()`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/typescript_nodejs/13.core-bot/src/dialogs/mainDialog.ts#L70), but I'm struggling to do this.

---

Another acceptable approach is to populate user's input text bot with `inputValue`, and have user hit enter. I'm unsure if adaptive-cards can support this behaviour, and how I'd implement this in Webchat channel.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own questions -

1. Treating as user input: for the action, use simple text instead of a data object in `welcomeCard.json`. This way Bot Framework automatically knows to treat it as user input

```
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Display Text",
      "data": "Text sent on behalf of user"
    },
```

2. Handling as user input: the trick is to add pass-through branches in the run method of mainDialog and intro step.

MainDialog.run()

```
        if (this.isWelcomeCardButtonAction(context)) {
            await dialogContext.beginDialog(this.id);
        } else {
            // handle normally
            const results = await dialogContext.continueDialog();
            if (results.status === DialogTurnStatus.empty) {
                await dialogContext.beginDialog(this.id);
            }
        }
```

introStep()

```
        if (this.isWelcomeCardButtonAction(stepContext.context)) {
            return await stepContext.next(stepContext.context.activity.text);
        }
       // handle normally
```

actStep()

```
if (this.isWelcomeCardButtonAction(stepContext.context)) {
            return await stepContext.beginDialog(
                Dialog.YOUR_DIALOG,
            );
        }

// handle normally, probably call your LUIS or CLU
```